# отправка даных с form базу данных mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

В базу данных ничего не  отправляется и показывает пустую строку:
Тест на англиском Тест №:1
Выбери имя учителя: S.лов
Имя студента:
Фамилия Студента:

1. He was an HONEST man.
   A) liar B) good C) bad D) truthful E) wonderful
2. The climate of Great Britain is MILD.
   A) difficult B) strong C) severe D) bad E) good

```
<?php
    require_once 'connect.php';
?>
```

```
<form method="post" action=" handler.php">
        <
        <input align="center"  name="tip_obiect" value="English">Тест на англиском  

  <input  name="varianta" value="1">Тест №:1</label>     
<br>
         <label for="Nume_Prof">Выбери имя учителя:</label>

        <SELECT>
<OPTION value=""></OPTION>
        <OPTION name="Nume_Prof" value="C.лов">S.лов</OPTION>
        </SELECT><br>
        Имя студента:
        <input type="text" name="Nume" size="20"><br>
        Фамилия Студента:
        <input type="text" name="Prenume" size="18"><br><br>

        1. He was an HONEST man. <br>
    <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="rad1"     Value="true" CHECKED >A) liar    </INPUT>
    <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="rad1"     Value="false">B) good    </INPUT>
    <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="rad1"     Value="false">C) bad     </INPUT>
    <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="rad1"     Value="false">D) truthful    </INPUT>
    <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="rad1"     Value="false">E) wonderful</INPUT>
 <br>

<br>2. The climate of Great Britain is MILD.<br>
    <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="rad2"     Value="true" CHECKED > A) difficult</INPUT>
    <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="rad2"     Value="false" >B) strong</INPUT>
    <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="rad2"     Value="false" >C) severe</INPUT>
    <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="rad2"     Value="false" >D) bad</INPUT>
    <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="rad2"     Value="false" >E) good</INPUT>
             </form>
```

---

//connect.php

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_password = '';
    $db_name = 'testare';

    $link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
```

if (!$link) {
            die(''.mysqli_connect_errno().' - '.mysqli_connect_error().'

');
        }

```
    echo "<p>Вы подключились к MySQL!</p>";
```

---

//handler.php

```
<?php

    require_once 'connect.php';
?>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Основы PHP и MySQL</title>
<style>
* { font-family:Calibri }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
// Получить данные из суперглобального массива $_POST и обработать их
$Tip_obiect = isset($_POST['Tip_obiect']) ? 
    rim(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Tip_obiect'])) : '';
    if (!empty($Tip_obiect)) {
    $link->query("INSERT INTO Obiect(Tip_obiect) VALUES ('{$Tip_obiect}')");

$nume = isset($_POST['nume']) ? 
    rim(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['nume'])) : '';
```

if (!empty($nume)) {
        $link->query("INSERT INTO Student(nume) VALUES ('{$nume}')");

```
$prenume = isset($_POST['prenume']) ? 
    trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['prenume'])) : '';
```

if (!empty($prenume)) {
        $link->query("INSERT INTO Student(prenume) VALUES ('{$prenume}')");

```
$varianta = isset($_POST['varianta']) ? 
    trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['varianta'])) : '';
```

if (!empty($varianta)) {
        $link->query("INSERT INTO test(varianta) VALUES ('{$varianta}')");

```
$Nume_Prof = isset($_POST['Nume_Prof']) ? 
    trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Nume_Prof'])) : '';
```

if (!empty($Nume_Prof)) {
        $link->query("INSERT INTO obiect(Nume_Prof) VALUES ('{$Nume_Prof}')");

```
        // Проверяем прошла ли операция (свойство affected_rows возвращает число строк, 
        // затронутых предыдущей операцией MySQL (в нашем случае 1)
        if ($link->affected_rows == 1)
            echo '<h1>даные </h1>';
        else
            echo '<p>Что-то пошло не так при попытке записи в базу данных</p>';
    }}}}}
?>
```

Comment: Что значит "показывает пустую строку"? Я, конечно, понимаю, что вы новичок в веб-программировании и всё такое, но код, который вы скинули, он фактически нечитаемый: чтобы человек смог помочь вам, ему придется этот ужас по-человечески отформатировать, а затем вникнуть в то, что же он делает. Я бегло пробежался глазами и заметил пока только то, что у вас атрибуты `name` и `value` что-то делают на элементе `<h3>`. При этом у этого же атрибута `name` значение начинается с маленькой буквы, а на PHP вы принимаете поле, которое начинается с большой буквы - это две разные переменные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имя в селекте ставится. 
 
Имена полей(name,value) пишите в нижнем регистре.
 
handler.php - ошибки. Функции rim вообще нет, замените на trim
Внизу стоит скрытое поле для отправки 'tip_obiect'
 
Страйтесь не использовать br - упрвляйте типом элемента(поставьте ему display:block; например)

```
<form method="post" action="handler.php">

  <h3 align="center">Тест на англиском </h3> 

  <span>Тест №:1</span><br>

  <span>Выбери имя учителя:</span>
  <select name="nume_prof">
    <OPTION value=""></OPTION>
    <OPTION  value="S.лов">S.лов</OPTION>
  </select><br>

  <label for="nume">Имя студента:</label>
  <input type="text" name="nume" size="20"><br>

  <label for="prenume">Фамилия Студента:</label>
  <input type="text" name="prenume" size="18"><br><br>

  <span>1. He was an HONEST man.</span> <br>
  <input type="radio" name="rad1" id="liar" value="true" checked />
  <label for="liar">A) liar</label>

  <input type="radio" name="rad1" id="goods" value="false"/>
  <label for="goods">B) good</label>

  <input type="radio" name="rad1" id="bads" value="false"/>
  <label for="bads">C) bad</label>

  <input type="radio" name="rad1" id="truthful" value="false"/> 
  <label for="truthful">D) truthful</label>

  <input type="radio" name="rad1" id="wonderful" value="false"/>
  <label for="wonderful">E) wonderful</label><br>

  <br>2. The climate of Great Britain is MILD.<br>
  <input type="radio" name="rad2" id="difficult"  value="true" checked />
  <label for="difficult">A) difficult</label>

  <input type="radio" name="rad2" id="strong"  value="false" />
  <label for="strong">B) strong</label>

  <input type="radio" name="rad2" id="severe"  value="false" />
  <label for="severe">C) severe</label>

  <input type="radio" name="rad2" id="bad"  value="false" />
  <label for="bad">D) bad</label>

  <input type="radio" name="rad2" id="good"  value="false" />
  <label for="good">E) good</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="tip_obiect" value="English"/> 
</form>
```

//handler.php

```
$tip_obiect = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['tip_obiect']));
    if (!empty($tip_obiect)) 
        $link->query("INSERT INTO Obiect(Tip_obiect) VALUES $tip_obiect");

$nume = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['nume']));
    if (!empty($nume)) 
        $link->query("INSERT INTO Student(nume) VALUES $nume");


$prenume = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['prenume']));
    if (!empty($prenume)) 
        $link->query("INSERT INTO Student(prenume) VALUES $prenume");


$varianta = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['varianta']));
    if (!empty($varianta)) 
        $link->query("INSERT INTO test(varianta) VALUES $varianta");


$nume_prof = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['nume_prof']));
    if (!empty($nume_prof)) 
    $link->query("INSERT INTO obiect(Nume_Prof) VALUES $nume_prof");

    if ($link->affected_rows == 1)
        echo '<h1>даные </h1>';
    else
        echo '<p>Что-то пошло не так при попытке записи вашего email в базу данных</p>';
```

Answer (score 2):

метод GET замени на POST в форме

```
<form method="GET" на <form method="POST"
```